# SELECT Current and Previous row WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id value
---------
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 a
5 t
6 y
7 a
```

I want to select all rows where the value is 'a' and the row before it

```
id value
---------
1 a
3 c
4 a
6 y
7 a
```

I looked into

but I want to get all such rows in one query.

Please help me start

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way might be to use variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (rn := if(value = 'a', 1, @rn + 1) as rn                 
      from table t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
      order by id desc
     ) t
where rn in (1, 2)
order by id;
```

An alternative method uses a correlated subquery to get the previous value and then uses this in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.value
              from table t2
              where t2.id < t.id
              order by t2.id desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_value
      from table t
     ) t
where value = 'a' or prev_value = 'a';
```

With an index on `id`, this might even be faster than the method using variables.